# ASP.NET MVC. Реализация авторизации, аутентификации и регистрации на основе готовой таблицы MySQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, авторизация, аутентификация, регистрация

Добрый вечер!

Пишу веб-приложение на ASP.NET MVC. Еще совсем новичок.

У меня есть готовая заполненная таблица `Users`, которая маппится в следующую модель:

```
[Table("risksdb.user")]
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        RiskRecords = new HashSet<RiskRecord>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int IdUser { get; set; }

    public int? IdRole { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<RiskRecord> RiskRecords { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**Вопрос**: Как на основе данного класса реализовать авторизацию, аутентификацию и регистрацию на сайте? В сторону каких библиотек, классов и интерфейсов посмотреть? Может быть, уже есть статья, отвечающая на мой вопрос, но я ее не нашел.

Я понимаю, вопрос слишком обобщенный, но я много статей пролистал, и везде предлагали реализацию через генерацию таблицы базы данных, а мне бы хотелось иметь свою структуру для хранения пользователей.

**UPD.** Конкретно мне нужно:

- При регистрации добавлять пользователя в таблицу базы данных (при этом проверять поле `Login` на уникальность).
- При авторизации и аутентификации: вводится `Login` и `Password`. По Login ищется запись в таблице, если записи нет - выводим сообщение, что записи нет. Если есть, то проверяем у записи поле `Role`(или `IdRole`) и если это обычный пользователь, то выводим ему одну страницу, а если это админ - то другую. При этом нужно сохранять данные авторизации до тех пор, пока мы не закрыли страницу сайта.

Comment: могу предложить ответ , только не понятно что вам надо конкретно ...Задайте конкретные вопросы ... Тема слишком обширная . Достаточно создать любой проект , включающий регистрацию пользователей , и посмотреть как там все реализовано , применить данные из примера относительно своей базы данных . Выкинуть все лишнее что вам не надо , а что надо  - подпилить под свои нужды .

Comment: @Eikhner добавил пояснение в вопрос. Взгляните.

Comment: @Eikhner я еще раз попробую на все это дело взглянуть в стандартном проекте MVC с авторизацией и отпишусь, что мне не понятно.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону Asp.Net Identity

Comment: прежде чем выводить для админа одну страницу,  а для пользователя другую  - может стоит подумать просто о доступе разных ролеи к меню ??? Или разному меню для разных ролеи ??? Они в _Layout могут задаваться ... например . А в контроллере , работающем с функциями администрирования задать доступ только пользователю с ролью администратора ?? <Authorize(Roles:="admin")> . По идее нужно начать с примера модели данных для регистрации пользователя ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По просьбам автора вопроса пишу статью о переходе на `MySQL` стандартной регистрации на `ASP.Net MVC`.

**Переход с `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` на `AspNet.Identity.MySQL`**

[Статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider) на официальном сайте.

Для перехода нужна версия Visual Studio Express 2013 или Web or Visual Studio 2013 с Update 2

Для перехода на `MySQL` выполните следующие действия:

1) Создайте в MySQL базу со своим названием и выполните запрос на создание таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` longtext,
  `SecurityStamp` longtext,
  `PhoneNumber` longtext,
  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockoutEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `userclaims` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ClaimType` longtext,
  `ClaimValue` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Claims` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `userlogins` (
  `LoginProvider` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ProviderKey` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LoginProvider`,`ProviderKey`,`UserId`),
  KEY `ApplicationUser_Logins` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Logins` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `userroles` (
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `RoleId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`,`RoleId`),
  KEY `IdentityRole_Users` (`RoleId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `IdentityRole_Users` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `roles` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ;
```

Конфигурацию файла так же можно получить по [этой ссылке](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/AspNet.Identity.MySQL/MySQLIdentity.sql).

2) Через NuGet найти и установить `AspNet.Identity.MySQL` и `MySql.Data`.

3) Через NuGet удалите `Identity.EntityFramework`.

4) Во всех файлах проекта (`IdentityModels.cs` в папке `Models`, `Startup.Auth.cs` и `IdentityConfig.cs` в папке `App_Start`) замените `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;` на `using AspNet.Identity.MySQL;`

> Указанные изменения в скобках 4-ого пункта могут не совпадать!

5) В файле `IdentityModels.cs` в папке `Models` найдите

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
```

и измените всё его содержимое на следующее

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : MySQLDatabase
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext("Connection_db_mysql");
    }
}
```

6) Откройте файл `IdentityConfig.cs` в папке `App_Start`. В

```
public static ApplicationUserManager
```

найти объявление переменной `var manager` и заменить её на:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>() as MySQLDatabase));
```

7) Откройте файл Web.config в корневой папке проекта и под строкой

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

добавьте

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection_db_mysql" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=pass;database=namebase;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

, где `localhost` - адрес, по которому находиться база данных, `root` - имя пользователя для входа в БД, `pass` - пароль для входа в БД, `namebase` - имя базы, в которой хранятся таблицы, которые мы установили в пункте `1)`.

После этого, всё должно заработать!

Comment: В принципе, неплохо! Спасибо Вам! Только остался 1 вопрос: как упростить эту базу данных? Но я думаю, дальше сам разберусь.

Comment: К сожалению, не смогу помочь в этом. Сам этим пока не занимался. Всегда думаю, что, всё что есть, может мне ещё пригодиться в будущем.